# Crash after call DetachCurrentThread

Tags: multithreading, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have a private lib that developed by my company. It allowed me to set a callback function, so after the long time operation completes, the callback will be called in sub thread.

I should operate JVM in the callback. This is my main code in the call back function:

```
JNIEnv *pEnv = NULL;
glJniContext.pJvm->AttachCurrentThread(&pEnv, NULL);
UiInkeyMsInternal(pEnv, 10000000);
glJniContext.pJvm->DetachCurrentThread();
```

The `AttachCurrentThread` is to attach the sub thread to the JVM, the `UiInkeyMsInternal` is to call a Java Method, and the `DetachCurrentThread` is to detach the sub thread to JVM, and `glJniContext.pJvm` is stored in the native method method like this:

```
JavaVM* gs_jvm;
pEnv->GetJavaVM(&gs_jvm);
glJniContext.pJvm = gs_jvm;
```

With the line `glJniContext.pJvm->DetachCurrentThread();` , The program will crash. But without the line, it's normal. How to analyse the phenomenon?

Another question, I can get JNIEnv variable by `AttachCurrentThread` method normally, but the `findClass` method doesn't execute normally. Whatever I pass, like "java/lang/Thread", it will return 0x00. Is this normal or can I ignore it?

Comment: Assuming `glJniContext.pJvm` is valid, the code seems fine.  (You might want to check the return value on `GetJavaVM` and `AttachCurrentThread`.)  What does the logcat output show when it crashes?  (Use `adb logcat` or the logcat view in ADT/DDMS.)

Comment: Thanks for you advice. I've checked both `AttachCurrentThread` and `GetJavaVM`, their return is 0(normal). It is strange that the program runs today normally, that's say it won't crash. The code is not changed, just the computer and the device is both rebooted. So I have not a direct way to analyse the reason.

Comment: @johnnyfee Suddenly, I've got the same symptoms in one of my project: `findClass` returns 0 and `DetachCurrentThread` fails. Have you managed to solve your situation?

Comment: @deko, the return value of AttachCurrentThread is Normal(JNI_OK)?

Comment: @johnnyfee Thank you for the answer. I've found the reason - it was another java module under development, which was not initialzed properly. I've commented for now it end everything is OK.

Answer (score 1):

Don't call `JNI handler function` from main `thread`. Calling `JNI handler function` from main thread will make crash.